# Can I use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity on .net core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working on porting an ASP.NET MVC application to an ASP.NET Core MVC hosted in .NET Core.

I was excited to see that EF 6.3 can host on .NET Core, since it looks like the EF -> EF Core migration is something that I'd at like to defer (possibly indefinitely).

Looking at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.* nuget packages, it appears that they don't have dependencies on a particular .NET framework (full or Core) just on Entity Framework 6.1 or greater.

Other than the purist idea that I should just move everything over to core while I'm in the code, is there any reason I can't have an ASP.NET Core MVC application that uses EF 6.3 and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` rather than EF Core and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`?

After some experimentation:

It looks like I was wrong and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` has a dependency on the full .NET framework. So I will revise the question:

Can I use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` with Entity Framework 6.3?  My key goal here is to avoid biting off the EF -> EF Core migration while getting the rest of my codebase moved to .NET Core.

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly. I have read on a blog post about that kind of problem you can use both libraries (Entity Framework 6 and Core) in the same project. As you know, Entity Framework 6 doesn't support everything to inject your ApplicationDbContext such as Core so you can create two different DbContext for Identity and other things and you can use the same time until you move your codebase to the core. If I find the blog post I'll share with you.

Comment: @mstfcck - Thanks, I would be interested in the blog post if you find it.  I may try to back up even further and see if I can get mvc core running on top of the full runtime working first.